# Get NSDate from string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I Have a date string that  I am trying to convert into NSDate to compare it with the current dateTime. I Have tried to implement this but and geting a null value for the date that im trying to convert.

This is what I have tried.

```
-(BOOL)checkTime{

    //create an instance of the database oject
    DataBase * dataBase = [[DataBase alloc] init];

    //get the times
    NSMutableArray *times = [dataBase allDataFrom:@"timings"];

    //set date time to string and refresh time to float.
    NSString *dateStr = times[1];
    float refreshTime = [times[2] floatValue];


    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    //get the time now
    NSDate* timeNow = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"dateStr: %@",dateStr);
    NSLog(@"DataBase Date: %@",date);
    NSLog(@"Current Date: %@",timeNow);
    NSLog(@"Time until refresh. (seconds): %f", refreshTime);

    // If date is greater than refresh then update the data
    if ([timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:date] > refreshTime)
    {
        NSLog(@"Data Needs to be checked.");
        return YES;

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Data is fresh.");

        return NO;

    }


}
```

This is what im getting from from logging all my values

```
dateStr: 2013/02/26  12:39:28
DataBase Date: (null)
Current Date: 2013-02-26 12:57:49 +0000
Time until refresh. (seconds): 30.000000
Data is fresh.
```

Have I got the syntax incorrect or could there be something else I have missed?

Comment: Show the values for the `times` array?

Comment: Have you seen this useful link http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/date-and-time/date-and-time-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the input date and the format!

Format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Input:

```
2013/02/26  12:39:28
```

(Slashes instead of hyphens and an extra space).

Comment: Thanks Thats was the case. Feel silly I missed it now :P

Answer (score 2):

As your this code  `NSLog(@"dateStr: %@",dateStr);` prints `dateStr: 2013/02/26  12:39:28`

And you are setting your dateformat as `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];`
That is why you are getting `NSLog(@"DataBase Date: %@",date);`DataBase Date: (null)`.

You need to do as :

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Thanks Thats was the case. Feel silly I missed it now :P